# Can nvidia ION's HDMI output to 2560x1600p ? (geforce 9400m, Aspire revo R3600)

Tags: resolution, hdmi, dvi, nvidia-ion, acer-revo

Will the  Aspire revo R3600 output to a "30-inch monitor (Samsung SynchMaster 305T) at 2560x1600 pixels with DVI-D-DualLink input" if I put a "HDMI to DVI-D-DualLink adaptator" on the HDMI port of Aspire revo R3600?

(Since Aspire revo R3600 has "Nvidia ion geforce 9400M" graphics card, can I access the DVI-D-DualLink port of the graphics card easily?)

Answer (score 1):

According to the specifications on [Nvidia's website](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_9400m_g_us.html), the 9400M can output up to 2560x1600 via digital connectors (e.g. HDMI).

Answer (score 1):

In short: NO. You need a 29-pin HDMI connection for it to be electrically compatible with Dual-Link DVI, and the Revo had the de facto 19-pin, which will only ever do single-link.

If you want WQXGA from a nettop, I think about your only choice atm is the Zotac ZBox HD-ID11 or HD-ND22.

Comment: I'd also consider the computing power of the box in question. Even if it is technically possible to output 2560x1600, I would be surprised if the nettop had enough power to drive it at acceptable frame rates. My own little Ion-powered nettop struggles to do anything meaningful at 1080p without stuttering.